# Is there a central font-license search site?

Tags: fonts, licensing, font-licensing

There are many font websites, that are eager to sell you fonts, or let you download them for free. So many that there is no way to know which are legit, and give the money to the copyright/license holder for the font. Is there a good central location to search who owns the copyright/license for fonts that can be found online?

In my current specific case, I am trying to find out if I can use "A L Heavenly" for commercial purposes, but have not been able to track down who owns the license beyond the name "[Autumn Leaves](http://www.fontineed.com/author/Autumn%20Leaves)", and that it has been [around since 2013](http://font.downloadatoz.com/font,74766,al-heavenly.html).

So is there a good way to track down authors when the licensing info on font websites is not completely trustworthy?

Note: yes, I realize the question is very similar to [Establishing the real copyright owner of a font](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7566/establishing-the-real-copyright-owner-of-a-font), but in my case, what I want to know is what options are available in terms of a reliable, trustworthy, website that has links to contact the font authors (something most sites I have run into do not seem to have) or which can be trusted when they state a font's license (as free, or licensed by paying through the site).

Comment: Google is about the best tool out there for this.